# How to check if a variable is string or an integer?

Tags: python, string, integer

I have a question about how to warn user to input `'string'` instead of `'integer'`
but it seems that I cannot iterate the loop if user input is `integer` and ask again `please enter string`

Example from here

http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

```
catNames = []

while True:

    print("Enter the name of cat " + str(len(catNames) + 1) + ' (Or enter nothing to stop):' )

    while True:

        name = input()

        try:
            name = int(name)

        except ValueError:

            print('please enter string')
            pass    

    if name == '':
        break

    catNames = catNames + [name] # list concatenation

print('The cat names are :')
for i in catNames:
    print(' ' + i)
```

Comment: That `name` will never break the outer while loop because input name is in another scope and the inner loop has nothing that breaks it, because if it gets a `ValueError` then it passes and runs again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is this:

```
catNames = []

while True:
    print("Enter the name of cat " + str(len(catNames) + 1) + ' (Or enter nothing to stop):' )
    name = input()
    if name.isalpha():
        catNames = catNames + [name] # list concatenation
    elif name == '':
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a string")


print('The cat names are :')
for i in catNames:
    print(' ' + i)
```

Answer (score 1):

One `while` is sufficent, in case a user enters an integer you could 'reset' the value:

```
catNames = []

while True:
    print("Enter the name of cat " + str(len(catNames) + 1) + ' (Or enter nothing to stop):' )
    name = input()

    if name.strip() == '':
        # no input
        print("exiting!")
        break

    try:
        name = int(name)
        name = None
        print("Please enter a string")
    except ValueError:
        pass
    finally:
        if name is not None:
            catNames.append(name)


print('The cat names are :')
for i in catNames:
    print(' ' + i)
```